# CruiseControl.Net Build Confirmation in CCTray

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Is there a way to make CCTray popup a confirmation dialog box when I click ForceBuild for a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is called `askForForceBuildReason` and documentation on it is located at http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Configuration+Block

example is:

```
<project name="Project name"
    description="Project description"
    askForForceBuildReason="required">

    ....

</project>
```

used in the `ccnet.config` file

Answer (score 0):

You can get CCTray to prompt you, I believe, By setting the askForForceBuildReason property to optional or required on a project.

As I understand it, CCTray will then prompt you for a reason.

Its not a confirmation, but does act as a prompt before forcing the build

**Example:**

```
<project name="name">
  <askForForceBuildReason>required</askForForceBuildReason>

   snip

</project>
```

Comment: Do you have an example? I googled `askForABuildReason` and only two results came back and none of them were useful.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct the property is called `askForForceBuildReason`, your answer below should suffice